# to be converted as array and separate to three rows of array

Tags: php

I want to separate this line `AT101A (1st Yr.-1st Sem) BSAT-12-01`
into this:

```
array1 = AT101A
array2 = (1st Yr.-1st Sem)
array3 = BSAT
```

This is my code:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");

while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false)
{
    $coursecode = $fileop[1];
    $units = $fileop[2];
    $day = $fileop[4];
    $timein = $fileop[5];
    $timeout = $fileop[7];
    $room = $fileop[8];
    $section = $fileop[0];

    if($section != "SECTION") {
        $section.split(" " , " ");              
        echo $section;
    } else {

    }
```

Comment: What is the question ? What is this code ?  What is this syntax ? What is... well, I didn't understood anything.

Comment: .split? is this php? Anyway, use explode to separate the string.. I don't get why you want to store it in THREE arrays when you can store it in one.

Comment: `$section.split`? PHP has only 2 object operators: `->` and `::`. Strings in php are simple data, they are not objects.

Comment: this AT101A (1st Yr.-1st Sem) BSAT-12-01 came from csv file
i imported it into my database
and i want to separate it into three categories
AT101A will be the section
(1st Yr.-1st Sem) will be the Term and
BSAT will be the course code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems entirely irrelevant to your problem. It even uses `.` notation which PHP does not have.

However, if we can use regular expression, the following code to will split the line:

```
$input = "AT101A (1st Yr.-1st Sem) BSAT-12-01";
$match_count = preg_match_all( "/^(.+?)(\(.+?\))(.+)$/", $input, $matches );

print_r($matches);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AT101A (1st Yr.-1st Sem) BSAT-12-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => AT101A 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => (1st Yr.-1st Sem)
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  BSAT-12-01
        )

)
```

post process:

```
$array1 = $matches[1][0];
$array2 = $matches[2][0];
$array3 = $matches[3][0];
```

### EDIT:

If your question is from any 'computer' classes, regular expression won't fit. The topic of the question might be 'splitting string with certain delimiters', with moderate use of loop/pointer/condition/concatenating/etc. Please have a look at [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function which can be helpful for solving your problem.